# Inserting strings into an SQL table depending on what results a query returns

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, insert-into

I have a handful of queries that I'm using to test whether or not database results from tests that I run don't have anything obviously broken and buggy in them.

One of the queries has this basic form:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE Column = ''
```

Its checking to make sure that one particular field is not blank. I want to keep track of these tests being run and when they pass or fail. Is there a way that I can write a query so that if that query brings back any results then it writes a string to another table that says something like "Test Passed"?

So, a pseudo version might look something like this:

```
IF (
    SELECT *
    FROM Table1
    WHERE Table1.Column1 = ''
) = 0
INSERT INTO Table2 (FileName, Date, Result)
VALUES ('File1', 'GetDate()', 'Test Passed')
ELSE
INSERT INTO Table2 (FileName, Date, Result)
VALUES ('File1', 'GetDate()', 'Test Failed')
```

And the table might look like this:

```
| FileName |   Date   |    Result   |
|:--------:|:--------:|:-----------:|
| File1    | 12-25-16 | Test Passed |
| File2    | 12-25-16 | Test Failed |
| File3    | 12-25-16 | Test Passed |
| File4    | 12-25-16 | Test Passed |
```

Comment: Just change the `SELECT *` to `SELECT COUNT(*)` and you've got it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You almost have it in your code.  Just change the `SELECT *` to `SELECT COUNT(*)` and you've got it .  I would set the status and then do the insert.

```
DECLARE @testStatus NVARCHAR(MAX);

IF (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM Table1
    WHERE Table1.Column1 = ''
) = 0
    SET @testStatus = 'Test Passed'
ELSE
    SET @testStatus = 'Test Failed'

INSERT INTO Table2 (FileName, Date, Result)
VALUES ('File1', GetDate(), @testStatus)
```

Comment: Thanks Steve, I have very little experience working with conditional statements in SQL and I assumed it had to be much more complicated than this. I think I'm going to post a new question about this because it seems outside the scope of this question but one thing I left out of the original question was making this apply to multiple databases.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way that I can write a query so that if that query brings back any results then it writes a string to another table that says something like "Test Passed"?

Building further on your query,you can do something like below

--No columns so test passed

```
    IF not exists ( SELECT *
        FROM Table1
        WHERE Table1.Column1 = ''
    ) 
Begin
    INSERT INTO Table2 (FileName, Date, Result)
    VALUES ('File1', 'GetDate()', 'Test Passed')
End
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve the result only with a query (without T-SQL) you can use this solution:

```
INSERT INTO Table2(FileName, Date, Result)
  SELECT 'File1', GetDate(), X.Result FROM (
    SELECT 'Test passed' Result
       WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Column1 = '')
    UNION ALL      
    SELECT 'Test failed'
       WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Column1 = '')
  ) X
```

With a little effort you can write also the Oracle version of the same query:

```
INSERT INTO Table2(FileName, Date, Result)
  SELECT 'File1', sysdate, X.Result FROM (
    SELECT 'Test passed' Result FROM dual
       WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Column1 = '')
    UNION ALL      
    SELECT 'Test failed' FROM dual
       WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Column1 = '')
  ) X
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MERGE 
   table2 AS target
USING 
   table1 AS source
ON 
   source.Column1 = ''
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
   INSERT INTO target (FileName, Date, Result)
   VALUES ('File1', 'GetDate()', 'Test Failed')
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
   INSERT INTO target (FileName, Date, Result)
   VALUES ('File1', 'GetDate()', 'Test Passed')
```